# MySql CONCAT add data to column beginning and end

Tags: mysql, csv, concatenation

I've succeed to add data to the beginning and the end of a column by using CONCAT, but would like to here if there is a smarter/faster command/way to do this.

JOB: I've got a csv dump from foreign domain which I have to modify to fit my website/DB. In the DB there is a column containing embed data for video player, but... the source CSV only have the `http://domain.com/embed.php?video=5894372` why i have to add `<iframe width="640" height="480" src="` and `" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>` to the these in the mod-DB.

What I have done with succes

```
UPDATE `DB_name`.`table_name` SET embed = CONCAT(embed,'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');

UPDATE `DB_name`.`table_name` SET embed = CONCAT('<iframe width="640" height="480" src="',embed);
```

DB column "embed" is varchar,255

Write your suggestion and why? I'm all ears

Comment: excuse me.... posting a question 3 mins ago and already -2 points!! don't you like new users on this forum? and just down voting with no explanation...   bad carma gays

Comment: This is not a forum.

Comment: Sorry if it's not answering the question directly, but what you're trying to do smells bad. There's content on one side, and what you do with it on the other side. Joining them together in a final result (the complete iframe tag is a final result) should only happen on the final step, which is not the data extraction step.

Comment: Hi Sebas... I'm not sure what you mean here... what's the pitfall in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can  use a singole update

```
    UPDATE `DB_name`.`table_name` 
    SET embed = CONCAT('<iframe width="640" height="480" src="', 
                         embed ,
                '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>' );
```

Comment: That would smarten it a skip one step :)

Comment: Hi scaisEdge looking for "better" or alternative ways to do this, and if there is a MySql command that could be used which use less resource to fulfill the job. Simply learning Mysql :)